# updating the JDK on a linux machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, xubuntu

I'm sure this is just my lack of experience with linux but I just cant seem to figure it out. I'm using XUbuntu annd I have the JDK6 installed and the full screen issue is really starting to bother me so I'd like to upgrade to version 7. I've tried installing it in the software center, I've tried 'sudo su apt-get install openjdk(whatever the rest of the package name is), I've tried using a package manager, I've even uninstalled version 6 then installed it and some how I end up with version 6 still. I'm sorry, I know I'm probably missing something entirely obvious but I cant figure it out.

Comment: I think this belongs to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=install+jdk+7) forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have several java versions in your machine you could use below command to change the version you required.

```
/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

This will ask to choose you a number and number contains the version belongs to it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Tip: bellow=emit a deep loud roar; below=underneath.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands:

```
$ java -version
$ which java
```

You will find out which version of JDK you are currently using. That said, install new version of JDK and make sure that it comes first in your PATH environment variable, i.e. update PATH like this:

```
export PATH=</path/to/new/jdk>:<current PATH>
```

To make it permanent, update .bash_profile or .profile file. Running again statements mentioned above should now give you new version of JDK.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I still haven't been able to get it to work completely but I appreciate it and at least I know to what I have to do now when I have time to mess with it.